# How to get Activity from which second Activity was started?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have `activity A`, `MyRecyclerAdapter`, and `activity B`.

In `activity A` I build MyRecyclerAdapter and start new `activity B` from recycler item click.

Now I need to access `activity A` in `onDestroy` method from `activity B`.
How can I do it?

**Update:**
I tried:

```
ActivityA parent = (ActivityA) getParent();
parent.setRead(id);
```

But it gives me null. I think it's because A is not a direct child of B;

Comment: Why do you need to access Activity A from onDestroy?

Comment: need to set readAllMessages() for my recyclerAdapter which I created in activity A. I want to mark all messages as read

Comment: Honestly, Activity B shouldn't be managing data in Activity A. You should think about another way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you should use [`startActivityForResult(intent)`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result). Then you override `onActivityResult()` in *activity A* to handle the data you receive after *activity B* was destroyed. In `onDestroy()` you'd just have to set the result with `setResult(resultCode, data)`.

Like this you don't need to know about *activity A* in *activity B*.

Comment: I don't have startActivityForResult() in recycler adapter. I tried context.startActivityForResult() - but there is no such method. I tried v.getContext().startActivityForResult() - no such method

Comment: The method is defined on `Activity`. So you need to give the data from your adapter to the hosting activity. Then from there you can start the other activity.

Comment: There is a better way: `((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_FOR_ACTIVITY_CODE);`

Comment: Also a possibility. But it's never good to assume that any `Context` is an `Activity`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should create an interface class declare a method and implement it in Activity A. Then call that method from Activity B.
Alternatively you can create a Runnable in Activity A which does what you want in the run() method. Then pass the instance of that Runnable with the intent data to Activity B. Then call run on that instance object from Activity B. That should execute the code in the run() method in Activity A.